# How to change url property for the HttpClient angular2 official class?

Tags: javascript, angular, httpclient

I'm trying to change the HttpClient class in angular2. I need to set it manually by code so once I change my URL path I can apply to it.
Here is the code:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
   // http.someproperty="new_url"
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/web/web-taxes/', '.json');

}
```

Is there a possibility to change the property and which property exactly to write my new URL. If not how can I solve this issue?

Comment: There is no such 'property'. HttpClient is a singleton, and a thing like that would result in making all requests to single url, which is nonsense. You have XY problem. If your case is TranslateHttpLoader, address it.

Comment: @estus what do you suggest?

Comment: Please, modify the question to reflect your real problem and not the problem you have with its expected solution (which is wrong). See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve